# How to partition and use heap memory allocated en masse with Rust?

Tags: memory-management, rust, flexible-array-member

I've read a lot on Rust lately but am still only beginning to oxidize. My brain retains most of its C/C++ reflexes so pardon me if this question is not relevant because of how things are done in Rust.

Is it generally possible (desirable?) to allocate a block of an arbitrary size on the heap and then map a data structure over it with bindings taking ownership of smaller chunks of memory?

Using C99, one may write this:

```
typedef unsigned char BYTE;

typedef struct {
    size_t size;
    BYTE payload[];
} flex;

// ...

flex * flex_new(size_t _size) {
    flex *f = malloc(sizeof(flex) + _size * sizeof(BYTE));
    f->size = _size;
    return f;
}
```

Flexible length arrays may prove useful e.g. when implementing memory pools with chunks of variable size or when allocating memory on the heap dedicated to a thread. The data structure which required size is only known at runtime is allocated in an 'atomic' fashion and its members packed contiguously.

I am wondering whether a similar Rust implementation is possible (without `unsafe` constructs) and if it is, what it looks like. Maybe the compiler may infer some information using lifetime specifiers in the `struct` definition?

Comment: There are probably good uses for it, but if so, they are likely using `unsafe`. It doesn't help that many libraries that you'd expect are doing this actually found different ways: `Vec` is a `(ptr, length, capacity)` triple rather than a pointer to `(length, capacity, items)`, and `Arena` piggybacks on `Vec`s that are never resized.

Comment: I was not aware of `Arena` and will look into it at once, thanks! I  should have stated that I don't care if `unsafe` is used as long as a safe interface is provided in `std` or as a candidate for it.

Comment: @delnan sounds like you should add that as an answer. ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of 'flexible length arrays,' you can use [`Vec::with_capacity`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/collections/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.with_capacity) to allocate more than your immediate need:

```
let mut vec: Vec<int> = Vec::with_capacity(10);

// The vector contains no items, even though it has capacity for more
assert_eq!(vec.len(), 0);

// These are all done without reallocating...
for i in range(0i, 10) {
    vec.push(i);
}

// ...but this may make the vector reallocate
vec.push(11);
```

For the more general case, [TypedArena](https://github.com/SimonSapin/rust-typed-arena) is what you'd want to use, though.

Comment: the link for Arena looks broken